# How to open a link in a native app?

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, android-webview

I want to open the link in the native app instead of it in the android webview. I have a code. But it does not checks all URL's. I want to make it universal for many URL-links. For example, if I click on the link http://instagram.com/somethingxy. Then I want, that the programm automaticly realizes, that it is an Instagram link and opens it directly in the native app.

That is the code that I currently have:

Method:

```
public boolean appInstalledOrNot(Context context, String paramString) {
    PackageManager localPackageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        //noinspection WrongConstant
        localPackageManager.getPackageInfo(paramString, 1);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Action:

```
String facebookPackage = "com.facebook.katana";

if (appInstalledOrNot(this,facebookPackage )) {
    String url = "https://m.facebook.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need deeplinking for that to happen!

There are many third party services that provide that like [Branch metrics](https://branch.io/) or Firebase's [Dynamic Links](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYhInbjo_YAhXDuY8KHZXhBTAQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fdynamic-links%2F&usg=AOvVaw00n6EM0AD6k8nI3Bo8VRX9)

Apart from their own documentation you can find blogs and samples that can help you with that, personally i feel Firebase's Dynamic Links is easier to implement and understand and here is a [blog](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwkpiIj4_YAhUIPo8KHQLnBCEQFgg2MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fexploring-android%2Fexploring-firebase-on-android-dynamic-links-7364def74808&usg=AOvVaw3TbMdPZglKMRgmJbTHqmAq) that can help you with it